# How to insert Spring application values in validation annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, hibernate-validator

In my following rest controller I'm requesting email-id from the user.

```java
@GetMapping("/user/{email}")
public Mono<Document> getDocumentsById(
            @NotNull @Email(regexp = "${email.regex}") @PathVariable String email) {

   return documentService.getDocumentById(email);
}
```

To validate email I have applied a very simple regex, whose value is stored in application.yml

```yaml
email:
    regex: "^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@google.com$"
```

But I'm not able to get the value here and I end up receiving the following message:

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: 
HV000032: Unable to initialize org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.EmailValidator.
```

Can someone guide me if this is possible or if I'm making any mistake. This regular expression is working fine when I replace ${email.regex} with actual String value in the annotation.

Comment: Sorry about my wrong answer. i deleted it. I just realized you want value injection in the constructor. If i find something like this i will post it. I would advise you to use value injection in the controller constructor and use that string as value.

Comment: Yes, I believe it's not possible to inject values directly into the regex. As an alt option I'm doing exactly what you have just suggested. Thanks for the help tho.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Pattern instead of @Email

Comment: Even with pattern also, if you try injecting the value from the application.yml file directly into the regexp, it will not convert it to value instead would treat it as a regex itself. I believe this is not possible.

Comment: which hibernate validator version are you using?

Comment: ```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>


```

Comment: hibernate-validator:6.2.0.Final